# Android emulator doesn't load

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am learning Android studio  right now, by following a tutorial series. I created a new project and just added (and formatted) a button in content_main.xml. I also created a new layout resource file named new_layout. I have not coded anything yet, but when I run the program in the emulator, the emulator is stuck on a screen with the google 'G' logo, loading infinitely. Even though the gradle build has finished, the Android emulator is not opening and just keeps loading. Please help.

Comment: Either post your solution as regular answer (not as question edit) or delete your question completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the virtual device had some problem, so making a new virtual device in the AVD Manager fixed it.